# Rails proper way to distinguish methods from variable names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

Now that my controllers are expanding beyond the basic REST actions it can get somewhat confusing as to whether a given expression is either a built in method, a controller method, from the model, or a variable.

Would adding empty parentheses to my controller methods when I call them from other methods cause any problems down the road? Like so:

```
if customer.save?
  subscription_checker()
end
```

I'm at least trying to always use an underscore in the names of the methods I create in order to make them look different from most of the built in methods.

Comment: Nope, using empty parentheses like that is not idiomatic. Rather, you should use naming to help you tell those apart (in cases when it matters)

Comment: For example, `subscription_checker` is a terrible name for a method (in this context). What does it do? Context suggests that it checks subscription, but the name suggests that it gets and returns you a checker object. You don't need that confusion.

Comment: As a side note, if your controller actions are growing to much (_beyond the basic REST_), maybe you should consider refactoring it into multiple controllers.

Comment: How do you confuse model method invocations with controller method invocations? You call model methods on some instance, you don't add explicit target for controller method invocations. What do you mean by *"built in method"*? Methods in `Kernel`? If yes - you just remember them after some usage. As for method vs variable, this is by design. You shouldn't care how you get your value.

Comment: If your controllers are getting too complex and you don't want to move the code into your model (or if it doesn't belong there), you could consider creating a service object (`CustomerService`) to encapsulate the logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would adding empty parentheses to my controller methods when I call them from other methods cause any problems down the road?

This is a valid way to distinguish between variables vs methods in ruby, but **"You're Doing It Wrong" ™**

Part of the ruby paradigm is that you shouldn't typically *care* whether the thing you're referencing is a variable or a method. This makes the code easier to read and refactor; keeping the developer's attention focused on code's intent rather than its implementation.

This design pattern is often referred to as "bare words", and I highly recommend the following RubyTapas episode on the subject: http://www.virtuouscode.com/2012/10/01/barewords/

I would also recommend that you have a quick read through a ruby style guide, to see what common conventions are considered "good" or "bad" by the community. (Ruby code styles are [extremely well conformed to](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) by the community!) For example, from [this guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/tree/e6ad9cd1472108f120299d3fef696f856579ebc0#syntax):

> Only omit parentheses for
>
> - Method calls with no arguments:
>
>   ```
>   # bad
>   Kernel.exit!()
>   2.even?()
>   fork()
>   'test'.upcase()
>
>   # good
>   Kernel.exit!
>   2.even?
>   fork
>   'test'.upcase
>   ```

In your particular code above, although it's hard to say for sure without knowing more context, I suspect that `subscription_checker` should actually be abstracted into a separate class rather than yet-another-method in the controller. But as I say, in order to give any concrete advice here I'd need to see more of the source file this is taken from.

Comment: Have my +1 for the barewords rubytapas episode reference. It's great, that one. :)

Comment: The usual solution is: if your code is so complex and your methods so big that you cannot tell which is which, you need to write less complex code and smaller methods.